# JavaFX: How to re-select TreeItem after TreeView update?

Tags: javafx, treeview, javafx-8, selecteditem, selectedindex

I want to update my TreeView. Before it I want to save selected TreeItem, and after update select it automatically. But when selected TreeItem disappeared, the NULL TreeItem must be selected.

Timer:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Platform.runLater(() ->{
                    updateUsbDeviceTreeView();
                });
            }
        }, 5000, 5000);
```

Timer Task function:

```
private void updateUsbDeviceTreeView() {
    TreeItem<UsbDevice> usbDeviceTreeItem = usbDeviceTreeView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    /////
        .....updating TreeView......
    /////
    usbDeviceTreeView.getSelectionModel().select(usbDeviceTreeItem);
}
```

But I faced with a trouble - if the previously selected TreeItem disappears, the TreeItem with the same ItemIndex that the previous one had, will be selected.

So, what is the problem with this adverse TreeView?

Comment: 1) How are you updating the treeview? Recreating all treeitems or what? 2) What do you mean eith NULL treeitem? Is it treeitem just has a string value "NULL"?

Comment: Can't you just check in the update code whether or not you are removing `usbDeviceTreeItem`, or at the very least iterate through all the `TreeItem`s after the update to check if it is there?

Comment: Uluk Biy, answer to you:
1) Yes, Im recreating all TreeItems. Set new RootItem, then set their children and so on...
2) NULL TreeItem means that nothing is selected (selected index = -1)

Comment: James_D, answer:
My update code just remove the last TreeView information "in one click".
Yes I can iterate through all the TreeItem, but I hope there is another nice method in javaFX to find TreeItem in TreeView. :)